# Background HTTP check with notification

Tags: c#, http, service, xamarin.forms, push

My Xamarin.Forms app need to make POST request to specific uri , and when it got something new it must send a notification

For notification I can use this. https://github.com/EgorBo/Toasts.Forms.Plugin

But I don not have any clue how to make app make HTTP request even when it`s on background or not even launched

Comment: I'd suggest checking out the NotifyIcon https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.notifyicon?view=netframework-4.7.2 when using a WinForms application.
I also suggest looking at http://restsharp.org/ if you want to get a look at simple HTTP requests.

Comment: @Logxn, sorry I forgot to mention that app is using Xamarin.Forms

Comment: @XLR8 If in background , you can use Task to make HTTP request.If not even launched ,this need native environment to do.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT so this is not possible to do with Xamarin.Forms? I tried to do with Services, but no luck with it.